# ontouchmove not call in javascript using android

Tags: javascript, android, svg

I am showing svg file using webview and drawing some tools using javascript on it. and for moving tools, i am calling startmove function using below code in there function like below:

```
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "ontouchstart", "startMove(evt,this)");
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "ontouchend", "drop(evt,this)");
```

functions are as below:

```
function startMove(evt,ele){

    console.log("----marker start moving----");

    if(isDrawing == '1')
    {
        return false;
    }
    document.getElementById("ssvg").style.cursor = 'move';
    drawObject='';
    drawLine=0;
    drawCircle=0;
    C=evt.target;
     handleCircleClick(ele);

    document.documentElement.setAttribute("onmousemove","moveIt(evt)");
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("ontouchmove","moveIt(evt)");

}


function moveIt(evt){

console.log("----marker moving----");
}
```

its working fine on android 5.0 and above version. but not working on android 4.4 and below default browser.

Comment: Try shape.[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - I have a hunch that it isn't parsing the event addition when setting the attribute with setAttributeNS()

Comment: @jedifans should i use addEventListener for ontouchmove only or for all events like ontouchstart, ontouchend.?

Comment: It's just something to try to see if it works. Try replacing touch start and touch end